# Find all Form Values and Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is supposed to find all fields in the form and submit them to a PHP page that will insert to mysql, but all I get back is an empty array. What is missing here? Don't I need a .val()?

```
<form id="form">
<table width="100%">
<tbody><tr><th>Displayname</th><th>URL</th><th>Parent</th><th>Sort Order</th><th>Active</th></tr>
<tr class="even"><td width="200">Settings</td><input type="hidden" value="1" id="Settings[0]"><td><input type="textbox" value="settings.php" size="75" id="Settings[1]"></td><td><select id="Settings[2]"><option selected="" value="0">No Parent</option><option value="1">Settings</option><option value="2">Grid Demo</option><option value="3">TEST</option><option value="4">Grid Options</option><option value="5">setGridOptions</option><option value="6">Menu Items</option><option value="7">Ajax Menu</option></select></td><td><input type="textbox" value="0" size="5" id="Settings[3]"></td><td><input type="hidden" value="INACTIVE" id="Settings[4]"> <input type="checkbox" value="ACTIVE" id="Settings[4]"></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td width="200">Grid Demo</td><input type="hidden" value="2" id="Grid_Demo[0]"><td><input type="textbox" value="grid.php" size="75" id="Grid_Demo[1]"></td><td><select id="Grid_Demo[2]"><option selected="" value="0">No Parent</option><option value="1">Settings</option><option value="2">Grid Demo</option><option value="3">TEST</option><option value="4">Grid Options</option><option value="5">setGridOptions</option><option value="6">Menu Items</option><option value="7">Ajax Menu</option></select></td><td><input type="textbox" value="100" size="5" id="Grid_Demo[3]"></td><td><input type="hidden" value="INACTIVE" id="Grid_Demo[4]"> <input type="checkbox" value="ACTIVE" id="Grid_Demo[4]"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
 <input type="submit" id="formsubmit">
</form>
<br><br>
<div class="contentarea2"></div>

 <script>
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    console.log('Submit Clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var postData = $form.serialize();
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "saveform.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData
    })
    .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // do something
        console.log('Submit Done');
    }//return what was found into <div>
    ,function (data) {
                $( ".contentarea2" ).html( data );
            },"html")
    .fail(function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: All of the form inputs are gathered in the serialize() function. If you watch the browser's console during the request you'll the data being posted. The console will also clue you in on everything else going on with the request / response.

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark: the variable $inputs is never used.  Should the next line be "var postDate = $inputs.serialize();" ?

Comment: Your inputs doesn't seen to have a `name` attribute.

Comment: what are you doing `var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");` for, if you are not going to use it anywhere? Remove it.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for the `.serialize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) says that:

> *Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string...For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, **the element must have a name attribute.***

Your form elements don't have a `name="something"` attribute. Give them a name and they'll be submitted.

Note that you don't need the `$inputs` variable (which you currently don't use after setting it anyway). `postData = $form.serialize()` will be enough on its own once you give your elements names.

Answer (score 0):

I got the right answer by asking it in a different way on a different question. As stated above, you do need to have name="something", then you can use a normal PHP form submission with this pasted at the bottom. No other changes needed to be made.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: $this.prop('method'),
        url: $this.prop('action'),
        data: $this.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the return of the php script
        }
    });
    return false; //prevent the form from causing the page to refresh
});
```